# How can I make a plotly graph on streamlit grouped by period?

Tags: python, plotly, streamlit

I'm trying to plot a line graph using Plotly + Streamlit, but grouping data by month.

I have this data:

```
id      date          grade
A       2020-01-01    100
B       2020-01-11    200
C       2020-01-21    500
D       2020-01-21    300
E       2020-02-01    100
F       2020-02-01    200
```

I want to plot the grade mean by month. This is what I got so far:

```
df = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%m/%d/%y %I:%M%p")

df_grouped = df.groupby(
    by=[df.index.month, df.index.year]
)

df.grade.mean().plot()
```

The problem is that I don't know how to do the same thing (or something close to) using plotly and on streamlit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified what kind of bar type you'd like, but I'm guessing a `go.Bar()` will do. But we can change that. For grouping and aggregating I would use the following approach:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df['months'] = df['date'].dt.month_name()
df_months = df.groupby(['months']).agg('mean').reset_index()
new_order = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
df_months['months'] = pd.Categorical(df_months['months'], categories=new_order, ordered=True)
df_months = df_months.sort_values('months')
```

Why so complicated? Because I'm assuming you'd like to have month names on your x-axis. And after grouping and aggregating values by month name, the order of the months can become messed up. The somewhat laborious approach above makes sure that doesn't happen, and that you can en up with this bar chart with the months in correct order:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E', 5: 'F'},
                     'date': {0: '2020-01-01',
                      1: '2020-01-11',
                      2: '2020-01-21',
                      3: '2020-01-21',
                      4: '2020-02-01',
                      5: '2020-02-01'},
                     'grade': {0: 100, 1: 200, 2: 500, 3: 300, 4: 100, 5: 200}})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df['months'] = df['date'].dt.month_name()
df_months = df.groupby(['months']).agg('mean').reset_index()
new_order = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
df_months['months'] = pd.Categorical(df_months['months'], categories=new_order, ordered=True)
df_months = df_months.sort_values('months')

fig=go.Figure(go.Bar(x=df_months.months, y=df_months.grade))
fig.show()
```

Comment: I was trying this code, but one thing got me thinking, this shouldn't work if I have multiple years, right?

Comment: @dummyds Perhaps not this exact approach. But there may be other ways. So I would suggest that you write it up as an answer and we'll take it from there